# why my not_EOL function in C cannot detect EOL

Tags: c, scanf, eol

```
bool not_EOL (char c) {

    return ((c != '\n') && (c != '\0'));
}

while (not_EOL(gradients[i])) {
            // Read a position factor pair
            int a=sscanf(gradients + i, "(%d %lf)", &column, &factor);
            printf("%d%c",a,gradients[i]);
            if (a!=2) {
                usage(usage_message);
```

2 (9 100) (29 0)
38 (9 100) (49 390.043)
39 (9 100) (49 390.043)
41 (9 100) (49 390.043)

This is my not_EOL function and the file I am using. It seems that it does not detect EOL. The printf() statement prints 2(2(0, then usage() is called.

Comment: Your function looks ok to me. Perhaps you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are you updating `i`?

Comment: @R Sahu I update my question with  a snippet of how I test the code.

Comment: `not_EOL ()` is not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Simplify the logic.

```
boo is_EOL(char c)
{
   return ((c == '\n') || (c == '\0'));
}

bool not_EOL (char c)
{
   return (!is_EOL(c));
}
```